# How to check if loaded address from dll is function or variable?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, dllexport

So I am loading functions with this syntax:

```
typedef void* (*unknownf)(
#ifdef __cplusplus
...
#endif
);
unknown funci=(unknownf*)GetProcAddress(dll, "SomeFunction");`
```

and data with this

```
typedef void* (*unknownd);
conversiontype *some=(unknownd*)GetProcAddress(dll,"SomeData");
```

How to check if address contains data or function? What else can be there?

Edit: Please is there some programmatical way how to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way I check IMAGE_DOS_HEADER of DLL for sections .data .edata .rdata and .reloc and then I try to determine in which section is the name.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first few bytes that the pointer is pointing at. If you see something like this:

```
55 89 e5
```

(on x86) or:

```
55 48 89 e5
```

(on x86-64)

then it's probably a function.